# Synchronizing Spawn game object in unity and using Photon pun 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon-pun

Working on Multiplayer Game using photon pun 2 in Unity. I am trying to synchronize Box which is spawned when player trigger a function. So i need to synchronize game object for all players.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9D3T.jpg)

Here is Spawning Code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zVVJ.png)

```
private void SpawnBox()
{ 
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs" , "PickableCube"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
} 

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{ 
    if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
    { 
        SpawnBox(); 
    } 
}
```

I want to synchronize the game object for all players so if any player let the game it should not effect the game objects which are spawned in map . I tried PhotonNetwork instantiate , and also Photon view and photon view transform is applied on the box.

Comment: What was the issue when using PhotonNetwork.Instantiate?

Comment: it's start spawning extra boxes , and when i try to move it , it give move in wrong directions and keep rotating and moving in map on it's own

Comment: Please include the instantiate code in your question, and any relevant code pertaining to the instantiation.

Comment: private void SpawnBox()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs" , "PickableCube"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       
      if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
      {
            SpawnBox();
      }
    }

Comment: One issue I noticed is that there is no constraint on who runs the Instantiate.  Imagine there are 2 players total, and P1 enters the trigger.  That player enters the collider on each client.  So P1 sees them enter and executes, P2 also sees them enter and executes.  Add a local player check before spawning the box.

Comment: Thank you now it's working good , One more thing when it's moving it goes to 0,0,0 position and after some time it comes back to drop position when player drop it .

Comment: Please create a new question for each additional question you have.  This helps people searching for answers in the future, otherwise it would get buried in an unrelated questions comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I noticed is that there is no constraint on who runs the Instantiate function.

Imagine there are 2 players total and P1 enters the trigger.
That player enters the collider on **each** client.
P1 sees them enter and executes Instantiate.
P2 sees them enter and executes Instantiate.

Adding a local player check before spawning the box will prevent each client from instantiating the box.

```
private void SpawnBox()
{ 
    if (!photonView.isMine) return; // Not our player, don't spawn box

    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs" , "PickableCube"), transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
}
```